# System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente prueba unitaria estoy utilizando **xUnit**

```
 public class RepositoryTest
    {
        private readonly Mock<IDataConnection> mockDataConnection;
        private readonly ISqlRepository<RepositoryEntity> sqlRepository;
        public RepositoryTest()
        {
            mockDataConnection = new Mock<IDataConnection>();
            sqlRepository = new SqlRepository<RepositoryEntity>(mockDataConnection.Object);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GetQuerysAsync_ReturnsResultss()
        {
            //Arrange
            var query = "SELECT TOP(1) * FROM   tbl_AppSistema";
            var expectedResult = new List<RepositoryEntity>
            { new RepositoryEntity { Id = 1, Nombre = "System1", Ip = "", Principal = false } };
            var mockConnection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
            mockConnection.Setup(c => c.QueryAsync<RepositoryEntity>(query, null, null,null, default))
                          .ReturnsAsync(expectedResult);
            mockDataConnection.Setup(c => c.CreateConnectionAsync())
                              .ReturnsAsync(mockConnection.Object);
            //Act
            var result = await sqlRepository.GetQuerysAsync(query);
            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result);
        }
    }
```

Me esta sacando el siguien error

System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: c => c.QueryAsync(query, null, null, null, null)
Extension methods (here: SqlMapper.QueryAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Creo que esta en la siguiente linea

```
  var mockConnection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
            mockConnection.Setup(c => c.QueryAsync<RepositoryEntity>(query, null, null,null, default))
                          .ReturnsAsync(expectedResult);
```

Pero no entiendo a que se debe este error

Comment: Si la respuesta ofrecida ayudó a resolver tu caso, por favor márcala como aceptada para mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Gracias por tu cooperación.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
mockConnection.Setup(c => c.QueryAsync<RepositoryEntity>(It.IsAny<String>(), null, null,null, default))
              .ReturnsAsync(expectedResult);
```

El detalle está en la entrada de datos, utiliza `It.IsAny<tipo de dato que necesites como parámetro>()`.